# Getting @Id of lazy-loaded @ManyToOne entity allways returns null

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, lazy-loading

I am using Hibernate 4.3.8.Final and have problem with retrieving @Id property of lazy fetched property: For attached classes calling `aidConfiguration.getChipApplication().getId()` allways returns `null`. Other properties, eg. `aidConfiguration.getChipApplication().getVersion()` returns correctly the value from DB. If `chipApplication` is not lazy loaded (see the comment in the code), then `aidConfiguration.getChipApplication().getId()` returns correct non-null value.

What am I dong wrong?

BTW I need it to be lazy.

BaseEntity:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true)
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    private String id;

    @PrePersist
    public final void generateUuid() {
        if (this.getId() == null) {
            this.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        }
    }

    public final String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public final void setId(final String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

AidConfiguration:

```
@Entity
@Audited
public class AidConfiguration extends BaseEntity {

    @Column
    @NotBlank
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) // if it is EAGER (defaut) then then aidConfiguration.getChipApplication().getId() returns correctly non-null value
    private ChipApplication chipApplication;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "aidConfiguration", cascade = CascadeType.ALL) // cascade for auto-saving and deleting items
    private List<AidConfigurationItem> aidConfigurationItems;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public ChipApplication getChipApplication() {
        return chipApplication;
    }

    public void setChipApplication(final ChipApplication chipApplication) {
        this.chipApplication = chipApplication;
    }

    public List<AidConfigurationItem> getAidConfigurationItems() {
        return aidConfigurationItems;
    }

    public void setAidConfigurationItems(final List<AidConfigurationItem> aidConfigurationItems) {
        this.aidConfigurationItems = aidConfigurationItems;
    }
}
```

ChipApplication:

```
@Entity
@Audited
public class ChipApplication extends BaseEntity {

    @Column
    @NotBlank(message = "Aid can not be empty")
    private String aid;

    @Column
    @NotBlank(message = "Product can not be empty")
    private String product;

    @Column
    @NotBlank(message = "Version can not be empty")
    private String version;

    @NotNull(message = "Network is mandatory")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Network network;

    @ManyToMany(fetch =  FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<AidTag> aidTags;

    public String getAid() {
        return aid;
    }

    public void setAid(final String aid) {
        this.aid = aid;
    }

    public String getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(final String product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(final String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public Network getNetwork() {
        return network;
    }

    public void setNetwork(final Network network) {
        this.network = network;
    }

    public List<AidTag> getAidTags() {
        return aidTags;
    }

    public void setAidTags(final List<AidTag> aidTags) {
        this.aidTags = aidTags;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bit late, but the issue HH-9588 is still unresolved, and I just had the same issue (XML mapping rather than annotations, though).

Could not get the id from the getter when the binding was lazy. Got it when eager or fetch join.

Fixed it by getting rid of the "final" modifier on the getId() accessor. (final here was an attempt to protect the way primary keys/identifiers are defined in the superclass for all the entities)

before :

```
public abstract class Foo  {

Long id;

public final Long getId() {
    return id;
}

protected final void setId( Long id ){
    this.id = id;
}
...
```

after :

```
public abstract class Foo {

Long id;

// No more final 
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

// No more final 
protected void setId( Long id ){
    this.id = id;
}
...
```

Now, I can get the Id with a lazy binding as well.

Seems to me that this "final" modifier does not allow Hibernate to proxy this accessor as intended. The other accessors being not "final", one can access their values from the proxy.

So, I wonder whether HH-9588 is really a bug or a misunderstanding of the hibernate ways ?

Comment: I am also have same problem. Can you share code, you used to fix this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That seems a bug, if you do not miss anything. I would report it on Hibernate's bug tracking system. It would be nice if you would update this answer afterwards with a link to the bug.

Comment: Reported at https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9588. I'll inform you if I get any information.